# How to insert avro data to clickhouse efficiently with clickhouse-go?

Tags: go, optimization, avro, clickhouse, apache-pulsar

### Background

Optimize memory usage

### Problem

1. How to use buffer to insert avro data to clickhouse?
2. Can I insert the avro data from consuming pulsar directly without unmarshalling and marshalling ?

### Code

1. Now I consume message from pulsar

```
msg, err := pulsarConsumer.Receive(ctx)
```

and send the msg to a channel

```
dataWriteChan <- msg
```

2. another function to receive msg from channel and use avro to unmarshal

```
msg <- dataWriteChan 
dataPayload := msg.Payload()

var avroData interface{}
err := avro.Unmarshal(avroCodec, dataPayload, &avroData)
```

and then send the avroData to a slice to cache

```
dataCache = append(dataCache, avroData)
```

3. Until dataCache  reaches 20M, program begin to marshal and insert to clickhouse

```
tmpBuf := make([]byte, 0)
bf := bytes.NewBuffer(tmpBuf)

config := goavro.OCFConfig{
        W:     bf,
        Codec: goavroCodec,
}

ocfWriter, _ := goavro.NewOCFWriter(config)

ocfWriter.Append(dataCache)
```

then use the buffer bf to generate sql

```
sql := fmt.Sprintf("INSERT INTO %s.%s (%s) FORMAT Avro %v", Database, TableName, cols, bf)
```

exec sql

```
conn.Exec(ctx, sql)
```

4. The above steps can insert avro data normally, I do not want to use Sprinrf to generate sql since it will malloc a new memory. So I want to use the buffer data and change to

```
sql := fmt.Sprintf("INSERT INTO %s.%s (%s) FORMAT Avro ", Database, TableName, w.cols)
conn.Exec(ctx, sql + "%s", data.String())
```

I don't know if this can save memory; But the bigger problem is it insert with a error!

```
 write to storage err: %!(NOVERB)%!(EXTRA string=code: 1001, message: avro::Exception: EOF reached)
```

### Several places with high memory consumption

```
1. avro.Unmarshal(avroCodec, dataPayload, &avroData)
2. ocfWriter.Append(dataCache)
3. fmt.Sprintf("INSERT INTO %s.%s (%s) FORMAT Avro ", Database, TableName, w.cols)
```

### Thank you

No matter whether you can help solve it or not, I also appreciated you are willing to spend time thinking together! This is very important to me.

Answer (score 0):

The driver itself which you appear to be using does not support avro format. You will need to marshall the data into a struct. You can then exploit the driver's appendStruct method.

Comment: I try to use 'batch' and 'appendStruct' with dataCache ,but it failed with `%!(NOVERB)%!(EXTRA string=code: 1001, message: avro::Exception: Invalid data file. Magic does not match:)`